# How to run phone-gap application on raspberry pi 2 on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, html, cordova, raspberry-pi2, iot

I was wondering if it is at all possible to run a `phone-gap` application on a `raspberry pi 2` running `Windows 10 IoT`.

I am currently setup to build the app in `C#`, but being able to develop an app using `HTML` technologies would make integrating the app with my web page a lot easier, and quicker.

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you want to run an application unrelated to IoT on a special-purpose IoT OS? Or do you want to read sensors, control motors with a Cordova application? In any case, Win 10 IoT is made for IoT and anything else is a very low priority.

Comment: Yes I want to run an application unrelated to IoT on a special purpose IoT device. Your comment helped me change directions quickly. I had been researching and was curious, but the more I looked around, the more I realized that it would not be possible based on the purpose of phone gap, and IoT. Maybe in the future it will be easier to do. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it works as Phonegap doesn't support Win10 UWP apps at least to date (see:http://phonegap.com/about/feature/)
You can develop your UWP apps in C#, C++, **JavaScript**, VB, Node.js, Python and Arduino Wiring.

### Source: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Faqs.htm#rpi2

Please Mark As Answered if you find this helpful.